# Как красиво вывести массив изображений в Android?

Tags: android

Нашел библиотеку, загружающую изображение из телефона на сервер.
Назад возвращается его url.

Библиотекой Glide просто вывожу его.

Хотелось бы красиво выводить все изображения, загруженные на сервер, например, так: [скрин](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uXJTVaReLTWqLOq9tgNM-UtwswQ0hAxC)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример того что вы привели возможно реализовать с помощью `RecyclerView`, также посмотрите `RecyclerView GridLayoutManager`.

Вот хороший ответ на ваш вопрос, так же подробный Гайд как это сделать просто и быстро stackoverflow.com - [ссылка на ответ.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587168/simple-android-grid-example-using-recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager-like-the)